# How to sense inserted or updated record in SQL tables via log table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, synchronization

I have to disjoint Database with some common tables, I can not do any modification on the tables of one database ( it is under use always, and I can not for example add a col to one table), but I need to sync these two databases every night. What is the best solution to do this job, for example is there any systemic stored procedure to sense any updated or inserted record in one table?
I should mention that, only one of these databases write in these  data bases?

Answer (score 0):

you can write some batch script to sync the tables every night, use some scheduler to start the script (or) i guess you can also use triggers

Comment: the problem is I don't know what's modified, and I don't want to update all row of one table to be same as the other one. I want to do this sync operation with minimal cost

Comment: create a column lastUpdatedTimeStamp which store the last updated time automatically. IF lastUpdatedTimeStamp is current day then update those columns alone